# NoSuchMethodException при получении private метода

Tags: java, исключения, рефлексия

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь получить private метод:

```
private static int getValue(String input) {
    char[] value = input.toCharArray();
    if(value[0] == '0')
        return Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(value[1]));
    return Integer.valueOf(input);
}
```

вот так:

```
 Method testGetValue = Seconds.class.getMethod("getValue", String.class);
        testGetValue.setAccessible(true);

        int i = (Integer)testGetValue.invoke(s, "00");
```

на этой строчке

```
Method testGetValue = Seconds.class.getMethod("getValue", String.class);
```

вылазит исключение NoSuchMethodException. Как исправить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getMethod()` возвращает только публичные методы.

Для того, чтобы взять приватный, попробуйте `getDeclaredMethod()`

Comment: Спасибо, не увидел, что Вы оставили комментарий

Answer (score 2):

Приношу извинение, но проблема решена - не `getMethod()`, а `getDeclareMethod()`